# android app stop receiving BLE data after hours of work

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app that gets data from Ble device, draw the data in a chart (using MPAndroidChart) and saves the data to file (using bufferedWriter).

Everything works fine, but when I run the app for long hours, suddenly the app doesn't receive any more data, it's not stuck cause when I press a button in the activity it responds, and in the Logcat it responds when I press on the screen.

I see in the Logcat that the data receiving logs stop coming and the line "D/BluetoothGatt: onBluetoothStateChange: up=true onBluetoothStateChange: Bluetooth is on" appears 4 times.
In the Android Profiler, I see that the allocated data increases slower prior the data stopping (see attached image).
[image: Android Profiler when the data stopped]

To run the app I'm using Samsung Tab A (2016) Android 7.

I'm not sure what should I check next and how to catch why this problem occurs?
Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are basically saying that Bluetooth crashes and gets restarted?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what happens. There is no crash exception, just data stop coming, the BT doesn't get restarted. The app is not crashing either, it's responsive.

Comment: Have you registered a BroadcastReceiver for the Bluetooth state change (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)? That way you can detect that.

Comment: I did registered Broadcast receiver and no log printed up when the problem occurrs...

Comment: 1. If you toggle Bluetooth from the settings menu, do you then see your receiver being called? 2. Do you have your app in the foreground the whole time you are receiving data? 3. How do you get the data, by repeatedly reading a characteristic or by notifications? 4. If you after the data has stopped coming call disconnect() on the BluetoothGatt object, do you get a onConnectionStateChange callback?

Comment: 1. I need to catch it again and check.
2. The app runs in the foreground the whole time.
3. I'm reading from characteristic.
4. Nothing is being called when the data stops, so I can't intercept it.

Comment: How do you perform the reads? Do you have a timer that reads every now and then or do you issue a new read request when you receive a read response? May I ask why you don't use notifications instead? For debug purposes, you could have a button that calls disconnect() on the BluetoothGatt object in your UI.

Comment: when I start a measurement with the BLE data, I call to start reading data from the device, from then the data flow every second until I press stop. the stop button performs disconnection, and it responds when I press it even when the data stops flowing for the unknown reason.

Comment: Can you see in your log that you send the read request but that you don't get the onCharacteristicRead callback?

Comment: The read request called only at the beginning of the measurement, after that the data keep flowing

Comment: No each read request delivers only one read response, which is given to you by onCharacteristicRead.

Comment: Not in my firmware